# Panache with MongoDB find distinct

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have documents with "tags" arrays as properties. Now I want to query all distinct tag-items.

```
{ 
  "name": "test1",
  "tags": ["tag1","tag2", "tag3"]
},
{
  "name": "test2",
  "tags": ["tag1"]
}
```

Solution in mongo shell:

```
db.ApiModel.distinct("tags")
```

which gives me:

```
["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```

But how can I achieve the same result with Panache? The PanacheMongoEntity does not offer a specific distinct method. Nor do i know how to use the `find` method to achieve my goal or if it even is possible using this method.

All I could possibly think of is finding all tags with `find("tags", "*")` (is * the wildcard?) and then dealing with duplicates in Java, but I don't believe that's the intended use.

Comment: I think, you can use the `PanacheMongoEntityBase#stream` method which returns a `Stream<T>`, which in turn can be used get your distinct values of a specific field ([Stream#distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--)).

Comment: Coming from Hibernate with SQL this looks like "bad code" because I retrieve everything and then narrowing it down. But I think this is the way to go? Is there a way to inspect the query it produces in the logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of the two methods to get distinct `tags` from the collection `test`.

```
public List<String> getDistinctTags() {
        return Tags
                .<Tags>mongoCollection()
                .distinct("tags", String.class)
                .into(new ArrayList<String>());
}

public List<String> getDistinctTags() {
        return Tags
                .<Tags>streamAll()
                .flatMap(e -> e.tags.stream())
                .distinct()
                .collect(toList());
}
```

Assuming the `Tags` class is defined as follows and represents the Panache entity:

```
@MongoEntity(collection="test")
public class Tags extends PanacheMongoEntity {
    public String name;
    public List<String> tags;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So the query itself only happens when i call .collect()? Because otherwise the streamAll() (it retrieves every document in my collection?) would be executed first and I'm getting everything and then using distinct in java rather than on the mongodb? Or am I thinking too SQL-centric?

Comment: Okay, this is about the second method of the `getDistinctTags()`. The query actually fetches all documents as a `java.util.stream.Stream`, to which the Stream methods `flatMap`, `distinct` and `collect` are applied. The first `getDistinctTags()` has the _distinct_ applied on the server and the results are returned.

Comment: The `PanacheMongoEntity.streamAll` returns a `Stream` with all entities of the type.

Comment: Ok so the first solution would be better performance wise, right? I'm just coming from the SQL world and retrieving the whole table and then doing operations on it in java would be bad practice.

Comment: The distinct query executes on the server and you get the _result_ of the operation in your Java application. Yes, the query running on the server is more efficient _and_ you might see a performance gain based upon your data and other factors like network, etc..